# Multiple has_many polymorphic relations return error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a polymorphic relation between "Service" and "Image" models. There will be more than one model related to Image model, but for now there is only one, so this is why "Image" model is polymorphic. I have also 4 different image types so i added 4 has_many relation in "Service" model. And "Service" model also has `"accepts_nested_attributes_for :images"` added to it.

So in _forms.html.erb, i have 2 different `fields_for` FormHelper, and each of them have different sources. But whenever i try to create new one i got `"undefined method [] for nil:NilClass"` error.

So here is the Service and Image models:

```
class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :images, as: :imageable, :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :images_title,-> {where "image_type = 2"}, as: :imageable, class_name: "Image", :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :images_icon,-> {where "image_type = 1"}, as: :imageable, class_name: "Image", :dependent => :destroy
    has_many :images_regular,-> {where "image_type = 3"}, as: :imageable, class_name: "Image", :dependent => :destroy

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :images


end

class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :imageable, polymorphic: true

    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

    enum image_type: {icon: 1, title: 2, regular: 3, slider: 4}

end
```

ServiceController:

```
def new
    @service = Service.new
    @images = @service.images.build

  end

  def create
    @service = Service.new(service_params)

    if @service.save


          @image_title = @service.images.create!(:image => params[:images_title][:image], :imageable_id => @service.id, :image_type => params[:images_title][:image_type])
          @icon_image = @service.images.create!(:image => params[:images_icon][:image], :imageable_id => @service.id, :image_type => params[:images_icon][:image_type])

      # if params[:images_icon]

      # end

      flash[:notice] = "Hizmet sayfası başarıyla oluşturuldu!"
      redirect_to admin_services_path
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Hizmet sayfası eklenirken bir hata oluştu. Lütfen tekrar deneyiniz!"
      render "new"
    end
  end

 private

    def service_params
      params.require(:service).permit(:service_name, :service_description, :meta_keywords, 
        images_title_attributes: [:id, :imageable_id, :image], images_icon_attributes: [:id, :imageable_id, :image])
    end
```

_form.html.erb:

```
<div class="control-group">
   <%= f.simple_fields_for :images_title do |image| %>


     <div class="controls">
        <label class="control-label">Hizmet Büyük Resimi</label> 
        <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
          <div class="fileupload-new thumbnail" style="width: 200px; height: 150px;">
            <% if image.object.nil? %>
              <img src="http://www.placehold.it/200x150/EFEFEF/AAAAAA&amp;text=no+image" alt=""/>
            <% else %>
              <%= image_tag image.object.image_url %>
            <% end %>
          </div>
          <div class="fileupload-preview fileupload-exists thumbnail" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 150px; line-height: 20px;"></div>
          <div>
            <span class="btn btn-file"><span class="fileupload-new">Resim Seç</span><span class="fileupload-exists">Değiştir</span>
              <%= image.input :image, input_html: { type: :file, class: "default"}, wrapper: false, label: false %>
              <%= image.input :image_type, :as => "hidden", :input_html => { :value => :title } %>
            </span>
            <a href="#" class="btn fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Sil</a>
          </div>
        </div>


     </div>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Service is being inserted correctly but in nested attributes i got an error. So have i done something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked with Polymorphic relations a lot and I've done exactly what you are trying to do here: http://6ftdan.com/allyourdev/2014/08/01/manual-polymorphic-creation-in-rails/ You are instantiating multiple "kinds" of images.  I show in my blog how to do it with an enum, it's the same thing with your **image_type** field.

The blog post covers everything from controller to the form.  In my example I instantiate four different kinds of the same record as nested attributes in a form.  So that will get the job done for you.

Briefly what you'll be changing is you only need one **has_many** line in Service for your images.  And the other major thing is you need to use **build** for each instance of the images that will be uploaded via the form.